If $R$ is PID then $M_n(R)$ is PID
Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain, is it true that $M_n(R)$ i.e the ring of matrices over $R$ is also PID?
My attempt: I know that the ideals in $M_n(R)$ is of the type $M_n(I)$ where $I$ is an ideal in $R$. But, how can I proceed further?

A PID must be commutative, $M_n(R)$ is rarely commutative

@Zima maybe he means that every left and right ideal is principal? But he should add more information what he exactly wants.

For $n>1$ (and $R$ with nonzero identity, if I must to say so) $M_n(R)$ is neither a domain nor commutative.  However, $M_n(R)$ is a left principal ideal ring if $R$ is (and likewise if $R$ is a principal right ideal ring.)

Let's consider a special case:
Take $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $n=2$, so $M_2(R)=M_2(\mathbb{Z})$.
Since $$\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\0&0
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
$M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is not a domain, thus not a PID.

As @Zima already pointed out, the answer is most likely “no”: given $R$ a PID, in general $M_n(R)$ is not a PID.
The answer is simple: the ring of matrices is never commutative, and the definition of PID explicitly requires commutativity.
To be precise, the only situations in which the ring of matrices is commutative are trivial: either $R$ is the trivial ring and $n=0$, or $n=1$ and $R$ is commutative, so that the matrix ring is canonically isomorphic to $R$ itself.
However, I don’t know whether this can be of any interest to you, but there is a way to relax some of the assumptions and make your statement that the matrix ring is a PID “almost true”.
You are correct in saying that every ideal of $M_n(R)$ is of the form $M_n(I)$ for some $ I \subseteq R$, ideal of $R$.
But this is only true if we ask ourselves about two-sided ideals of $M_n(R)$ and $R$.
But, if we ask ourselves how to find one-sided ideals of $M_n(R)$, then the situation changes completely.
Take $R$ to be a field, for simplicity’s sake, and consider the set of matrices which are completely zero, except for the first column, which can be filled in any possible way. It shouldn’t be hard to see that this set is a left ideal of $M_n(R)$, call it $I_1$.
There is nothing special about the first column: you can do the same spiel with any other column and so you obtain $n$ left-ideals of $M_n(R)$: $I_1, I_2, \dots, I_n$.
You can do the same trick considering matrices which are all zero, except for a single row, you get $n$ different right ideals of $M_n(R)$, which you could call $J_1, \dots, J_n$.
If you consider the sum of any two or more of these ideals, you get matrices which are all zero except for two or more columns or rows, and they’re still left ideals or right ideals, respectively.
It shouldn’t be hard to notice how these ideals are all one-sides principal ideals nonetheless.
The element that generates by is the matrix which is completely zero, except along the main diagonal, where it has ones for every row/column that it is saved.
In the case where $R$ is a field, all left and right ideals of $M_n(R)$ are of this form and thus they’re all one-sided principal.
So even though $M_n(R)$ may not be a true PID, it nonetheless has all principal ideals: basically, it is the non-commutative version of a PID.
The case where $R$ is not a field shouldn’t be too different, even though I haven’t thought about an answer yet.

"In the case where $$ is a field" Actually one can say much more generally that $M_n(R)$ is a right (resp left) principal ideal ring if $R$ is a right (resp. left) principal ideal ring.

Right, so OP’s claim was actually almost correct. It suffices to replace “PID” with “left (resp. right) principal ideal ring”!
